# Chatapp using nodejs and socketio

Tags: android, node.js, android-studio, socket.io, real-time

i am trying to build my chat app. The server side and client side code is attached. when i install it it successfully get installed without giving any error. but it could not communicate to the server i also want that server can handle multiple clients. One thing that is surprising when i install it in my phone it successfully get installed and communicate to server but on any other device or emulator it could not communicate?. how can make this app that multiple clients connects on server and chat?

**server side script**

```
const express = require('express'),
http = require('http'),
app = express(),
server = http.createServer(app),

io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
app.get('/', (req, res) => {

res.send('Chat Server is running on port 5000')
});
app.set('port',(process.env.PORT||3000))

io.on('connection', (socket) => {

console.log('user connected. id:   '+socket.id)

socket.on('join', function(userNickname) {

        console.log(userNickname +" : has joined the chat "  );

        socket.broadcast.emit('userjoinedthechat ',userNickname +" has joined the chat ");
    });


socket.on('messagedetection', (senderNickname,messageContent) => {

       //log the message in console

       console.log(senderNickname+" :" +messageContent)
        //create a message object
       let  message = {"message":messageContent, "senderNickname":senderNickname}
          // send the message to the client side
       io.emit('message', message );

      });


 socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log( ' user has left ')
    socket.broadcast.emit("userdisconnect"," user has left ")

});



});





server.listen(app.get('port'),function(){
console.log('Node app is running on port ',app.get('port'));

});

**Client side**
```

try {

```
        socket = IO.socket("http://ipaddress:8080").connect();

    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);

    }

    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(!messagetxt.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                socket.emit("messagedetection", Nickname, messagetxt.getText().toString());
                messagetxt.setText(" ");

            }
        }
    });
    socket.on("join", new Emitter.Listener() {

        public void call(final Object... args) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    String data = (String) args[0];
                    socket.emit("join"+Nickname);


                }
            });
        }
    });
    socket.on("disconnect", new Emitter.Listener() {

        public void call(final Object... args) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                    String data = (String) args[0];
                    socket.emit("disconnect",Nickname);
                   // Toast.makeText(ChatBoxActivity.this,data,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
        }
    });
    socket.on("message", new Emitter.Listener() {
        Message m;
        public void call(final Object... args) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
                    JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
                    try {
                        //extract data from fired event
                        String nickname = data.getString("senderNickname");
                        String message = data.getString("message");
                        m = new Message(nickname,message);

                        MessageList.add(m);
                        chatBoxAdapter = new ChatBoxAdapter(MessageList,ChatBoxActivity.this);
                        chatBoxAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        myRecylerView.setAdapter(chatBoxAdapter);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    });
}

@Override

protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    socket.disconnect();
}
enter code here
```

Comment: socket.emit("join"+Nickname); In android, replace comma for the plus icon then only the nickname goes as a parameter. Otherwise, the join function is not triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with node and html. it's working

**Client Side**

```
console.log('Server connection started');
var socket = io();
var date = new Date();
var Nickname = "Karthik"+ date.getTime();

socket.on('join', (data) => {
    console.log('join', data);
    socket.emit("join", Nickname);
})

socket.on('disconnect', (data) => {
    console.log('disconnect', data);
    socket.emit("disconnect", Nickname);
})

socket.on('message', (data) => {
    console.log('message', data);

    // socket.emit("message", Nickname);
})

socket.emit("messagedetection", Nickname, 'Hi Test.');
console.log('Server connected', socket);
```

please check the emit and on function.

**Server side**

```
const express = require('express'),
    http = require('http'),
    app = express(),
    server = http.createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

app.use(express.static('node_modules'))
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    res.send('Chat Server is running on port 5000')
});
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3000))

io.on('connection', (socket) => {

    console.log('user connected. id:   ' + socket.id)
    socket.on('join', function (userNickname) {
        console.log(userNickname + " : has joined the chat ");
        socket.broadcast.emit('userjoinedthechat ', userNickname + " has joined the chat ");
    });

    socket.on('messagedetection', (senderNickname, messageContent) => {
        console.log(senderNickname + " :" + messageContent)
        //create a message object
        let message = { "message": messageContent, "senderNickname": senderNickname }
        // send the message to the client side
        io.emit('message', message);

    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log(' user has left ')
        socket.broadcast.emit("userdisconnect", " user has left ")
    });
});

server.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log('Node app is running on port ', app.get('port'));

});
```